# What's the difference between using range() and using a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Given an list of colors:

```
colors = ["blue","brown","red","yellow","green"]
```

**1.**

```
for color in colors:
```

**2.**

```
for index in range(len(colors)):
```

what is the difference between using **1** and **2** ?

Comment: Do you get the same result when running each line? If not, there is your difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say `for color in colors:` you are iterating over the items in the list.

```
for color in colors:
    print(color)

>>> "blue"
>>> "brown"
>>> "red"
>>> "yellow"
>>> "green"
```

If you iterate over indices you get:

```
for index in range(len(colors)):
    print(index)

>>> 0
>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
>>> 4
```

You can get the two version together by using `enumerate`:

```
for c, color in enumerate(colors):
    print(c, color)

>>> 0 "blue"
>>> 1 "brown"
>>> 2 "red"
>>> 3 "yellow"
>>> 4 "green"
```

Comment: And you can get both with `for index, color in enumerate(colors)`

Answer (score 1):

With the first one you'll have access to local variable color within loop. It's also considered more pythonic.

With the second one you'll have access to the index instead which might be useful.

I'm not aware of performance difference but someone might be.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to change each string in the list to uppercase. If you use the first method, each item in the list is basically copied to the temporary variable `color`. You can change `color` if you like, but that doesn't change the list itself.

```
for color in colors:
    color = color.upper()
print(colors)
>>>['blue', 'brown', 'red', 'yellow', 'green']
```

When you call `range` and `len`, you can change the items in the list, since you have their index.

```
for index in range(len(colors)):
    colors[index] = colors[index].upper()
print(colors)
>>>['BLUE', 'BROWN', 'RED', 'YELLOW', 'GREEN']
```